# Python: convert 2 lists to dict and repeat the keys with each set of data

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Learning about Python's zip function.  I can do this

```
list_keys = ['fname','lname','dob']
list_data = ['bob','smith','12121950']

keys_and_data = dict(zip(list_keys,list_data))
print keys_and_data
#output
{'lname': 'smith', 'dob': '12121950', 'fname': 'bob'}
```

Now I am trying to figure out how to get this to work

```
list_keys = ['fname','lname','dob']
list_data = [['bob','smith','12121950'],['john','jones','10101940']]
keys_and_data = ??
print keys_and_data
#output
{['lname': 'smith', 'dob': '12121950', 'fname': 'bob'],
 ['lname': 'jones', 'dob': '10101940', 'fname': 'john']}
```

How do I get python to repeat the keys?

Comment: The second output does not make sense.  I'ts a set/dictionary with a list that looks nothing like a list.  Did you mean `{` where you've written `[` and vice versa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loop over `list_data` in a list comprehension:

```
keys_and_data = [dict(zip(list_keys, data)) for data in list_data]
```

Demo:

```
>>> list_keys = ['fname','lname','dob']
>>> list_data = [['bob','smith','12121950'],['john','jones','10101940']]
>>> [dict(zip(list_keys, data)) for data in list_data]
[{'lname': 'smith', 'dob': '12121950', 'fname': 'bob'}, {'lname': 'jones', 'dob': '10101940', 'fname': 'john'}]
```